# How to get product collection outside of Magento2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1 I can use

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

Where is the new "*`/app/Mage.php`*" in Magento 2?
What file I have to include in my external PHP file?

Comment: you can check here for more reference: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-create-my-dirty-playground-file-in-magento-2/40839#40839

Answer (score 1):

### Call of Application:

Try this

In magento2 There no app.php

**It have bootstrap.php which is main hero magento 2**.

```
    use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager;

require YoutmagetoDir. '/app/bootstrap.php';
 /* set Parameters for application */

$opt['group'] = 'default';
$opt['standaloneProcessStarted'] = '0';
$params = $_SERVER;
/* you can out your store id here */
$params[StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'admin';
$params[Store::CUSTOM_ENTRY_POINT_PARAM] = true;

/* create application */
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/* the applocation 
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cron $app */

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Cron', ['parameters' => $opt]);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

- `createApplication()` initialize `magento application`

  On above example function we have send the store code(PARAM_RUN_CODE) as admin.
- `run()` function is execute the `application`