# Magento 2 Order Collection + Customer Collection

Tags: magento2, orders, magento-2.1, export

I want to make a PHP file to get Orders and Customers from a Magento 2 based webshop (like exporting). I have a full code for Magento 1, but for M2 I have tried a lot of things.

I also needed this function for Products but now I have this.

If anybody can add a full code for Orders and Customers I would be glad, if I found one I will paste it.

---

Here is the code to get products, base on this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91193/34384

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
\Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('session_start');
use \Magento\Framework\AppInterface as AppInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State as State;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Http as Http;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as RequestHttp;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as ResponseHttp;
use Magento\Framework\Event;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\AreaList as AreaList;

abstract class Magento_ClearAdmin_Abstract_getProducts implements AppInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        State $state,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        Event\Manager $eventManager,
        AreaList $areaList,
        RequestHttp $request,
        ResponseHttp $response,
        ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
        $this->_state = $state;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_areaList = $areaList;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_configLoader = $configLoader;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }
    public function launch()
    {
        $this->run();
        return $this->_response;
    }
    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    abstract public function run();
}
```

---

```
class getProducts extends Magento_ClearAdmin_Abstract_getProducts
{

    public function run()
    {
        return $this->getProductsXML();
    }
    private function getProductsXML()
    {
        $products = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $products = $products->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        foreach($products as $product)
        {

            ....

        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this:

Base class:

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
use \Magento\Framework\AppInterface as AppInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State as State;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as RequestHttp;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as ResponseHttp;

abstract class Magento_Abstract implements AppInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        State $state,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        ResponseHttp $response,
        ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader
    ) {
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
        $this->_state = $state;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_configLoader = $configLoader;
    }
    public function launch()
    {
        $this->run();
        return $this->_response;
    }
    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    abstract public function run();
}
```

get products:

```
class getProducts extends Magento_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        return $this->getProductsXML();
    }
    private function getProductsXML()
    {
        $products = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $products = $products->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');

        foreach($products as $product)
        {
                $product->getId(),
        }
    }
}
```

get customers:

```
class getCustomers extends Magento_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        return $this->getCustomersXML();
    }
    private function getCustomersXML()
    {
        $partners = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
        $partners = $partners->getCollection()->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_firstname', 'customer_address/firstname', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_lastname', 'customer_address/lastname', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_street', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('shipping_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('shipping_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('shipping_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('shipping_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('shipping_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('shipping_street', 'customer_address/street', 'default_shipping', null, 'left');
        foreach($partners as $partner)
        {
                $partner->getId(),
        }
    }
}
```

get products:

```
class getProducts extends Magento_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        return $this->getProductsXML();
    }
    private function getProductsXML()
    {
        $products = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $products = $products->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        foreach($products as $product)
        {
                $product->getId(),
                $product->getName(),
        }
    }
}
```