# follow-up question to "dirty playground" file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Based on this answer to a very similar question:
[How can I bootstrap Magento 2 in a test.php script?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-create-my-dirty-playground-file-in-magento-2), specifically https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76382,

when I run `php abstract.php`, I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Magento\Framework\AppInterface' not found in /var/www/html/scripts/abstract.php on line 14

It's probably very basic, please forgive me, but can anyone point me in the right direction?

`scripts/abstract.php`, from the above link, looks like

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\AppInterface as AppInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Http as Http;

use Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as RequestHttp;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as ResponseHttp;
use Magento\Framework\Event;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\AreaList as AreaList;
use Magento\Framework\App\State as State;

abstract class AbstractApp implements AppInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        Event\Manager $eventManager,
        AreaList $areaList,
        RequestHttp $request,
        ResponseHttp $response,
        ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader,
        State $state,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_areaList = $areaList;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_configLoader = $configLoader;
        $this->_state = $state;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function launch()
    {
        $this->run();
        return $this->_response;
    }

    abstract public function run();

    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`abstract.php` is not supposed to be run by itself. There's nothing in that file to load Magento or its autoloader, and the class is declared `abstract` (you can't use it directly). It's failing because there's a class name PHP doesn't know what to do with by itself.

In the answer you linked, there is a second script `scripts/delete-category.php` demonstrating how to actually use it. You need to create that second file, and then run that script (`php scripts/delete-category.php`). You can change the name and contents of this one's `run()` method to fit your needs.

That should get you up and running.

That being said, I just submitted another approach to that question. It's a little more involved than the standalone files you're trying (you need an actual module), but it's more proper for Magento. See: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/102901/1905