# programatically import csv - magento 2

Tags: magento2, import, csv, importexport

I have a **bpmn** tool, it will generate **CSV**, that CSV contains single product. I need to import that csv file programatically. Already magento admin have that feature.

please can anyone point key code to trigger that import module from cron Job?

Comment: This answer should help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102922/programmatically-create-a-simple-product-in-magento-2

Comment: it seems like we fetch csv data after that applied in your suggested answer, but I'm looking something just point the csv into the import module, it will handle the whole process of product creation like admin what does. I'm not sure about this so I need to research about this. If you need any clarity, please mention in comment.

Comment: Maybe not usefull, but Magento 2 EE have a schedule Import Module. You can try to find community extension in the marketplace or create your own CRON which trigger the same admin method which handle the import process.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me. Please click here for more details.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/code-snippets/import-simple-products-magento-2-programmatically/

```
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $product->setTypeId('simple');
        $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')); 
        $product->setName($importProduct[1]); 
        $product->setSku($importProduct[3]);
        $product->setWeight($importProduct[16]);
        $product->setStatus(1);
        $category_id= array(30,24);
        $product->setCategoryIds($category_id); 
        $product->setTaxClassId(0); // (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
        $product->setVisibility(4); // catalog and search visibility
        $product->setColor(24);
        $product->setPrice($importProduct[11]) ;
        $product->setCost(1); 
        $product->setMetaTitle($importProduct[1]);
        $product->setMetaKeyword($importProduct[26]);
        $product->setMetaDescription($importProduct[28]);
        $product->setDescription($importProduct[27]);
        $product->setShortDescription($importProduct[27]);

        $product->setStockData(
            array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
            'manage_stock' => 1, // manage stock
            'min_sale_qty' => 1, // Shopping Cart Minimum Qty Allowed 
            'max_sale_qty' => 2, // Shopping Cart Maximum Qty Allowed
            'is_in_stock' => 1, // Stock Availability of product
            'qty' => (int)$importProduct[6]
            )
        );


        $product->save();
        echo "Upload simple product id :: ".$product->getId()."\n";
    }
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Something failed for product import ' . $importProduct[1] . PHP_EOL;
    print_r($e);
}
```