# Programitically Import products using CSV in video url not set magento2?

Tags: magento2, import, csv

I have created a script for import CSV products everything's working perfect but one issue is product video url not set.

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');

// add bootstrap
$bootstraps = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$object_Manager = $bootstraps->getObjectManager();

$app_state = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');

// get date 
$today_date = date("m/d/Y");
$added_date = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("+17 day"));

$set_product = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

try{
    $set_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
    $set_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
    $set_product->setTypeId('simple');
    $set_product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')); 
    $set_product->setName('Test Sample Products'); 
    $set_product->setSku('add-sku-1');
    $set_product->setWeight(1.0000);
    $set_product->setStatus(1);
    $category_id= array('3,4,5');
    $set_product->setCategoryIds($category_id); 
    $set_product->setTaxClassId(0); 
    $set_product->setPrice(100.99) ;

    $set_product->setStockData(
        array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
        // checkbox for 'Use config settings' 
        'manage_stock' => 1, // manage stock
        'min_sale_qty' => 1, // Shopping Cart Minimum Qty Allowed 
        'max_sale_qty' => 2, // Shopping Cart Maximum Qty Allowed
        'is_in_stock' => 1, // Stock Availability of product
        'qty' => 100 // qty of product
        )
    );

     $set_product->save();
    // get id of product
    $get_product_id = $set_product->getId();
    echo "Upload simple product id :: ".$get_product_id."\n";
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$set_product->setVideoUrl('youtub.com/magento');
```

But it's not working category save and set product video URL?

Answer (score 2):

Please remove **single quotes** from **category id** array. So it is look like below.

```
$category_id = array(3,4,5);
```

Comment: Thanx @ Bhavin. you know how to set product video URL?

Comment: No sorry. I am still not use video URL in product.

Comment: ok, no problem. thanx for the solution. let me know if you found solution about video.

Comment: how to remove existing categories and add new categories using setCategoryIds?

Comment: @jafar When you use setCategoryIds, Magento automatically replaced existing with new one..

Comment: hi @BhaviniFlair, I tried it, but it will add the new category not replacing existing one

Comment: It is working fine for me.