# Update products and customer data in csv

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, import, cron

I need to add a functionality to import products and customers periodically (lets say once a 6 hours), from a given csv files.

Can I write an external script for those imports?

I tried to import data programatically, but without doing that, can I just directly use the csv file and add a cron job or similar thing to product import?

Can I use the php cron jobs to do the same task done at product import at magento admin panel?

Basically I'm looking for a script to read csv file and do the product import using that csv. without doing something like [this, mentioned in another question.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102922/programmatically-create-a-simple-product-in-magento-2)

Need to trigger admin panel product import for my csv by custom script. can anyone please help me?