# Magento 2.1 Update Product Stock in Cron Job

Tags: magento2, cron, stock, magento-2.1, sku

I need to be able to programmatically update product stock in my Cron job.  I have an array that contains both the SKU of the product needing updating and the Stock value of that product.  How can I select a product by SKU and then update the stock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about your data array which contains the SKU product and Stock value. So, I will use simple data.

We can update product stock via API:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/StockRegistry.php**

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php**

```
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        //Our sample values
        $sku = '100098';
        $stockValue = 5;

        $productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
        $stockRegistry = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

        //Load product by SKU
        $product = $productRepository->get($sku);
        //Need to load stock item
        $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
        $stockItem->setData('qty',$stockValue); //set updated quantity

        //$stockItem->setData('manage_stock',$stockData['manage_stock']);
        //$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock',$stockData['is_in_stock']);
        //$stockItem->setData('use_config_notify_stock_qty',1);

        $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
```

You can quick test our code lines by using playground:

[How can I bootstrap Magento 2 in a test.php script?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-create-my-dirty-playground-file-in-magento-2)

http://www.boolfly.com/magento-2-playground/

Comment: This looks like it would work, however I keep getting the "Class 'Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager' not found" message.

Comment: I have just update my code.

Comment: $objectManager=\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

This is the line that is throwing the error.

Comment: Tried to clear Magento Cache? How you test my code?

Comment: I am running the code in my cron job script located in Custom/Module/Cron/Script.php.  Something tells me I am missing some sort of dependency injection or something like that.   I have tried clearing the cache.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great example! This updates stock status too? I mean, out of stock events & related stuff if qty = 0

Comment: We can set the config: `STORES > Configuration > CATALOG > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Out-of-Stock Threshold`