# Is there a quick way to update stock levels in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, importexport, manage-stock

We need to update the stock levels of lots of products following off-site sales. Rather than click though to the details of every product, is there a way of quickly updating the stock figure from a table view without having to leave the table?

Or is the best way to `export/import` and amend via a spreadsheet?

I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Thanks

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128191/magento-2-1-update-product-stock-in-cron-job

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5771

Answer (score 2):

it is not good practices to update inventory direct from database table. You can import it using CSV or programmatically using below code :

```
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($entity_id);
$stockItem->setData('qty', $qty);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', ($qty > 0 ) ? 1 : 0); 
$stockItem->save();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Best and easy way is to update product stock is

Go to `admin side -> Catalog -> Products -> Select products` from the grid which you want to update stock

After that click on `Action dropdown -> select Update Attrbites`

[image]

after that go to `Advanced Inventory` tab and manage your stock like quantity etc

Comment: Thanks Hitesh - I can see this is useful for applying the same stock level to many products, but I need to update each individually and am trying to avoid having to click through to the product details of every product.

Comment: Ok go it, then you can do first export your all products do your changes of quantity and others, and re-import it all

Comment: you can follow this link https://www.alexcorradi.org/blog/a-guide-on-how-to-import-export-products-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

It's not best practice, but you can also use a direct SQL method which would be much quicker - though as it wouldn't trigger a product save, it wouldn't destroy the cache for those products so you would need to flush cache.

Here's the sql to show you the sku, stock position and whether its marked as in stock;

```
SELECT p.sku, i.qty, i.is_in_stock 
FROM dbname.cataloginventory_stock_item i, dbname.catalog_product_entity p 
WHERE p.entity_id = i.product_id 
AND i.stock_id = 1
```

Obviously ensure that if the stock position is greater than 0, make sure is_in_stock is set to 1, otherwise set it to 0.