# Magento2 Base,Small & Thumbnail image is not setting by Programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, image

**I am using below code to set the image as base,small and thumbnail,** but it is not working.

```
$productRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$product = $productRepository->get($sku);
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
```

Can anyone suggest, what is wrong with the code

Comment: still not working?

Comment: Thanks for the Answer,Let me try by this weekend and let you know

Comment: How about your current issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, Magento 2 has a test to set Base, Small and Thumbnail image **dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Sitemap/_files/sitemap_products.php**.

We can follow the logic of this and create your own. An simple example:

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem */
$filesystem = $obj->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface $mediaDirectory */
$mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
$mediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath();

//Sample product id
$productId = 1;
$model = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product = $model->load($productId);
$product->setImage(
            $mediaPath . '/magento_image.png'
        )
        ->setSmallImage(
            $mediaPath . '/magento_image_small.png'
        )
        ->setThumbnail(
            $mediaPath . '/magento_image_thumb.png'
        )
        ->addImageToMediaGallery(
          $mediaPath . '/first_magento_image.png',
            null,
            false,
            false
        )->addImageToMediaGallery(
            $mediaPath . '/second_image.png',
            null,
            false,
            false
        )
        ->save();
```

We can try to test my code with [playground](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-create-my-dirty-playground-file-in-magento-2) and [here](http://www.boolfly.com/magento-2-playground/).

Answer (score 0):

This code builds the image. You can either set the type on one image for all images types or individually:

```
            $mgEntry =
        $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface');
            $fileok = @fopen($imagePath, "r");

            if ($fileok) {
                $fileData = file_get_contents($imagePath);
                if ($fileData) {
                    $imageLabel = 'label_value';
                    $mgEntry->setLabel($imageLabel);
                    $mgEntry->setDisabled(false);
                    $mgEntry->setFile($imagePath);
          //          $mgEntry->setTypes(["image", "small_image", "thumbnail"]);
                    $mgEntry->setTypes([$type]); //thumbnail etc
                    $mgEntry->setStoreId(0);
                    $mgEntry->setMediaType('image');
                    $mgEntry->setPosition(0);
                    $imageData = base64_encode($fileData);
                    $imageContent =
                    $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterface');
                    $imageContent->setName($imageLabel);
                    $imageContent->setType($fileType);
                    $imageContent->setBase64EncodedData($imageData);
                    $mgEntry->setContent($imageContent);
                    array_push($mgEntries, $mgEntry);
                    $position++;
                    @fclose($fileok);
                } 
            } else {                
                $error = error_get_last();
                $this->logger->info("not able to get image file because {$error['message']}");
            }
```

Add each of the $mgEntry values to an array, and then add the array to the product

```
$magentoProduct->setMediaGalleryEntries([mgEntry array]);
```