# How to set thumbnail image programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, image, products

How can I set main product image as thumbnail image programmatically in Magento 2?

Scenario:

I have a loop running trough all products and each product has a main image, only some products have not defined an image for thumbnail. So I want to set the main image also as the product thumbnail for each product.

Comment: You should take a look here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/129869/magento2-base-small-thumbnail-image-is-not-setting-by-programmatically/129884#129884

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the reply.

I already found the answer by myself and I will share it below.

```
foreach ($products as $product){

    $smallImage = $product->getSmallImage();
    $imagePath  = '/catalog/product' . $product->getImage();

    if( $smallImage == 'no_selection' ){
        echo 'FIXING ' . $imagePath . "\r\n";
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery( $imagePath, array( 'small_image' ), false, false );
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

But still, I'm curious to know what are the Boolean variables are here.

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery( $imagePath, array( 'small_image' ), false, false );
```

Comment: The first is $move - if true, it will move source file. The second is $exclude           - if set true, mark image as disabled in product page view

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); // Load product object
$mediaAttribute = array ('thumbnail','small_image','image');

$mediaDir = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList')->getPath('media');// Im Magento 2
$mediaDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');// In Magento 1





//Case 1: When image files are alredy in your server
$fpath = 'product/images/';// path to your file
$count = 0;
$imgArray  = array('image1.png','image2.png','image3.png','image4.png');
foreach ($imgArray as $image){
    $imgUrl = _save_image( $fpath.$image,$objectManager,$mediaDir );// copies the file from your local storage to  your-magento-root-path/pub/media   
    if ($count == 0){
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery( $imgUrl , $mediaAttribute, true, false ); 
    }else {
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery( $imgUrl , null, true, false );
    }
    $count++;  
}

function _save_image($img,$objectManager,$mediaDir) {
    $imageFilename      = basename($img);    
    $image_type         = substr(strrchr($imageFilename,"."),1); //find the image extension
    $filename           = md5($img . strtotime('now')).'.'.$image_type; //give a new name, you can modify as per your requirement


    if (!file_exists($mediaDir)) mkdir($mediaDir, 0777, true);
    else chmod($mediaDir, 0777);

    $filepath           = $mediaDir . '/'. $filename; //path for temp storage folder: pub/media
    file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($img))); //store the image from external url to the temp storage folder
    return $filepath;
}
```

In your case set only 'thumbnail' in $mediaAttribute array.Hence array will be $mediaAttribute = array ('thumbnail');

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I already found an answer and posted it here.