# How to create image using Base64EncodedData in magento 2

Tags: magento2, image

I want to create images using Base64EncodedData in Magento 2.

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 provides some APIs to work with images:

`vendor/magento/framework/Api/ImageContent.php`
`vendor/magento/framework/Api/Data/ImageContentInterface.php`
`vendor/magento/framework/Api/ImageContentValidator.php`
`vendor/magento/framework/Api/ImageProcessor.php`

Let's go to this file: `dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Api/AccountManagementCustomAttributesTest.php`, we can find some testing cases:

```
        $testImagePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '_files' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'test_image.jpg';
        $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($testImagePath));
        $image = $this->imageFactory->create()
            ->setType('image/jpeg')
            ->setName('sample.jpeg')
            ->setBase64EncodedData($imageData);
```

We can try to test with [the playground file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-create-my-dirty-playground-file-in-magento-2).

Comment: I have also have a good guide here: http://www.boolfly.com/magento-2-playground/

Comment: thanks for the answer. But, it is related to customer . If I want to create an image for product then what should I do.

Comment: What dependency is `$this->imageFactory`?