# How to use magento2 function in root file

Tags: magento2

create test.php file in magento2 root, i want require baseUrl 
also i try to

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
```

but it's not work

Comment: Check this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-create-my-dirty-playground-file-in-magento-2

Answer (score 4):

It's work

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$obj->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend'); // for remove Area code is not set error
$storeManager = $obj->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
echo $baseUrl=$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

Comment: It's work but it will give error like Area code is not set in

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectManager  = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager   = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$baseUrl        = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

OR To get base dir path use ::

```
$myModuleDir = BP . '/app/code/MyVendor/MyModule';
```