# Magento 2: Calling Custom File on Root Gives RuntimeException

Tags: magento2, custom, server-setup

I'm calling Magento 2 Outside Magento using below ones

[How can I bootstrap Magento 2 in a test.php script?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-create-my-dirty-playground-file-in-magento-2)

My URL `abc.com/test.php` in 'test.php` it contains code.

It gives below error

**Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: The specified "/var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerFactory.php.10709" file could not be written Warning!file_put_contents(/var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerFactory.php.10709): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:115 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Custome...') #1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Custome...') #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Custome...') #3 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Relations/Runtime.php(38): class_exists('Magento\Custome...') #4 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(153): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime->has('Magento\Custome...') #5 /var/www/html/m in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on line 115**

Before this line it works fine

```
$url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
```

After this line it gives error.

Comment: make sure you have write permissions on `var/generation`.

Comment: Yes it's already have `0777` permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No permission change is required.
Instead you need to add a line at the beginning of this script. The revised code is below :

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$storeManager = $obj->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();
```

Comment: Run below commands & it's working fine `chmod -Rf 777 var`
`sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
`sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/di/*`

Comment: Can you assist me on this question, how to run outside out the root? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270717/how-to-run-external-script-outside-of-magento-2-root-directory

Answer (score 1):

The below code will work:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap; // this line is a must, otherwise it will generate error
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend'); // for remove Area code is not set error
$storeManager = $obj->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
echo $baseUrl=$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```