# How can 'dirty playground' use for Order Shippment - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, shipment

I am using '[Dirty Playground](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-create-my-dirty-playground-file-in-magento-2)' for external retrieve/update Magento products & order information. It's working fine.
Now, I am trying to update shipment from the same concept, but not able to achieve. It is showing a blank page.
I had tried updating [shipment by programmatic](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-shipment-programmatically-in-magento-2/), it's also working fine in Magento frontend.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../shoppersbay/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

    // Load the order static ID for testing 
    $order = $obj->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
        ->loadByAttribute('increment_id', '000000040');
// Check if order can be shipped or has already shipped
        if (! $order->canShip()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                            __('You can\'t create an shipment.')
                        );
        }

        // Initialize the order shipment object
    $convertOrder = $obj->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
    $shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
        // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
        if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
            continue;
        }

        $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();

        // Create shipment item with qty
        $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);

        // Add shipment item to shipment
        $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
    }

    // Register shipment
    $shipment->register();

    $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

    try {
        // Save created shipment and order
        $shipment->save();
        $shipment->getOrder()->save();

        // Send email
        $obj->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
            ->notify($shipment);

        $shipment->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                        __($e->getMessage())
                    );
    }
```

How can I achieve this? Am I missing something in the code?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, We achieve this by below changes. I am using  for getting order details. As per "dirty playground" **ObjectManager** has been already created, so we can't create again.

> $order = $obj->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
>           ->loadByAttribute('increment_id', '000000040');

```
$order = $obj->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
                ->load('38');
```

I replace all **$obj->get** with **$obj->create**, now it's working fine.