# Cancel the orders which are older than 3 days

Tags: magento2, checkout, cron, order-success-page

I'm trying to execute cron job after customer click place order button and redirect to success page. So the purpose of my job, if admin did not respond the order in 3 days, the order status will automatically canceled.

I have override the **\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success** in my module and use `execute` function to run my job via terminal.

```
<?php namespace Mymodule\Checkout\Controller\Onepage;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success
{
    /**
     * Order success action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        exec('php bin/magento cron:run --group="custom"');
        return parent::execute();
    }
}
```

Here is **crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="custom_group">
        <job name="test_cronjob" instance="Mymodule\Checkout\Cron\CancelOrder" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * */3 * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Here is **CancelOrder.php**

```
<?php namespace Mymodule\Checkout\Cron;

class CancelOrder {
    protected $orderFactory;

    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ){
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $orderId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
        if (!empty($orderId)) {
            $order = $this->orderFactory->create();
            $order->load($orderId);

            if ($order->getStatus() == 'pending') {
                $order->setState('canceled');
                $order->setStatus('canceled');

                $order->save();

                // send email to customer
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i try place order, the job is not executed. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I will suggest you to use an observer. Observe, if the order successfully placed then execute a cron from config.xml. It much better than yours.

Comment: Why not run cron each day and filter past 3 days orders if found cancel those orders. why do you want to run cron command in success ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to cancel the orders which are older than 3 days. In this case, we need to **create the Cron job**. So, we will **compare the current date with the created date** (take a look table `sales_order`, find the column `created_at`).

We should use Service Contracts Layer:

- `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository` and 
      `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder` are used for getting the order items.
- `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface` is used for canceling order.

Our Cron:

```
namespace Mymodule\Checkout\Cron;

class CancelOrder
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $orderRepository;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface
     */
    protected $orderManagement;

    /**
     * CancelOrder constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
    )
    {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $agoDate = '2016-11-07'; // For example date, your logic to calculate the date here
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
        ->addFilter(
            'created_at',
            $agoDate,
            'gt'
        )->addFilter(
           'status'
           'pending'
           'eq'
        )->create();

        $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        foreach ($orders->getItems() as $order) {
                $this->orderManagement->cancel($order->getEntityId()); // Cancel Order
        };

    }
}
```

You **should set your Cron runs every minute:** https://crontab.guru/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="custom_group">
        <job name="test_cronjob" instance="Mymodule\Checkout\Cron\CancelOrder" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**NOTE:** You can test your custom Cron directly: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152812/33057

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May i know what is the meaning of `'gt'` and `'eq'` in addFilter section?

Comment: Ahh, greater than and equal. right.

Comment: Yeah, you're right!

Comment: You also can test your Cron directly: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152812/33057

Comment: I still confused about how i run cron job automatically. Apparently i use terminal to run my group `bin/magento cron:run --group="custom_group"`

Comment: @SeventhSt should read this carefully: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: I have a problem while running my job. In messages field at `cron_schedule` table i got error **Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/tukurek-master/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---63c_DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 663**

Comment: @SeventhSt check the permission for `var` folder. You can try with 777.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh For Magento 1 how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own cron job that will automatically cancel orders older than 3 days filtered by order status.

Comment: I have created it.. Should i put them in my question?

Comment: Have you also setup your crontab to run Magento cron? Yes put more information with your code.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Forget Success rewrite and on your cron model filter for orders older than 3 days with status pending and then cancel them.