# How Magento 2 converts the namespace path to actual file path?

Tags: magento-2.1, script, conversion, paths

I know in Magento 2.x versions the namespace is converted to actual file path to load classes runtime.

For example, `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` is converted to `path\to\webroot\magentorootdir\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product.php`, but how this conversion done ? Is there any built-in function for this?, if yes, then where is it ? Can that function be called in a [dirty playground](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-bootstrap-magento-2-in-a-test-php-script) script ?

Answer (score 1):

Magento's autoload functionionality can be found in `/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php`. Here is where the autoload handler gets registered:

```
public function register($prepend = false)
{
    spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'), true, $prepend);
}
```

This class is instantiated by `/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php`'s `getLoader` method. This is also where the various maps get build using the `autoload_*.php` files, for example `autoload_static.php` builds the map for Magento's modules, for example:

```
'Magento\\Catalog\\' => 
array (
    0 => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/magento/module-catalog',
),
```

So when a class such as `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` needs to be instantiated, a call is made to `ClassLoader->loadClass('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')` which in turn calls `$this->findFile(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product)` to try and find a matching file name based on `ClassLoader`'s mappings and then includes the file if it exists.

All of this happens as a result of `app/autoload.php` being included, so I guess that's what your 'dirty playground' script would need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its based on the Framework Magento uses.

Basically you define the Namespaces of each modules which then get pumped into an huge iterator that holds ALL methods which are registered within such modules.

From your example you might wanna utilize `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`. The file descriptor is not needed since the classname is the same as the filename. If you check product.php you will see it yourself.

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Catalog\Model;

class Category extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\AbstractModel ...
{
```

So if you are trying to debugging some outputs you might wanna enable Block Name output. From there on you can further debug.

Dont get confused if you see Folders **and** files with the very same name. Differences are, that the folders doesn't contain any methods, but further `.php`-files and the file itself contains an actual class.

Example:

`\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category` = vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category.php

`\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute` = vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/Attribute.php