# How to input and return data from bootstrap Magento 2 test.php script?

Tags: magento2

I need to pull product data out of Magento 2 via an external PHP command line script.

I am using the example here: [How can I bootstrap Magento 2 in a test.php script?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-bootstrap-magento-2-in-a-test-php-script/76382#76382)

In the run method, I extract my product collection and parse my product data into a new array without any problem.

```
public function run()
{
   // create collection

   // parse collection

   // build $_products data array

    return ['data' => $_products];

}
```

If I dump or echo `$_products` out in `run()` I can see the product data ok, I need to return the product data to the calling function but cannot see how to retrieve the data. I am initiating my app with

```
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Getapp');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

How can I access the data **returned** from Getapp and how can I pass variables **into** Getapp?

Answer (score 1):

To return data from `run()` using the command line external php script example here [How can I bootstrap Magento 2 in a test.php script?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-bootstrap-magento-2-in-a-test-php-script/76382#76382)

use `$app->launch()` instead of `$bootstrap->run($app)` set the response variable and return it

```
public function launch()
{
    $this->_response=$this->run();
    return($this->_response);
}
```

Access the data with

```
$mydata=$app->launch();
```

You can also save the data in a class variable in `run()`

```
 $this->_mydata=$data
```

And access it via `$app`

```
$mydata=$app->_mydata
```

To make variables available to `run()` add the variables in an array to the bootstrap construct

```
    $app = $this->__bootstrap->createApplication(
        'Magento',
        array(
            'variables' => array(
                'product_id' => '65')
            )
    );
```

Add this to the "AbstractApp"

```
abstract class AbstractApp implements AppInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        Event\Manager $eventManager,
        AreaList $areaList,
        RequestHttp $request,
        ResponseHttp $response,
        ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader,
        State $state,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $variables = []
    ) {

        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_areaList = $areaList;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_variables=$variables;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_configLoader = $configLoader;
        $this->_state = $state;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }
```

Access the variable array in `run()`

```
$product_id=$this->_variables['product_id'];
```