# Magento 2: Add To Cart functionality from external site

Tags: magento2

I have my products in Magento db but I am borrowing the cart module from external site through an API. So basically when a customer clicks on "ADD TO CART" button, the product details are sent to the external site via a post API call,  now using a get API call I am retrieving the cart details from the external site. But I am not getting which particular classes do I need to override in Magento so that cart displays the product details retrieved from the API.
Also I am sending the product details to the external site by overiding the addProduct method in checkout module. Is this the correct way? I am confused about the parameters that are passed there i.e $product & $requestinfo .
Can you please clarify my doubts. Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is very good post with details about how to run Magento 2 on script - then you can add to cart or do many other things https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-bootstrap-magento-2-in-a-test-php-script