# Magento 2 Not able to override \Magento\Directory\Block\Data Class

Tags: magento-2.2.1, override-block

I am trying to override Block `\Magento\Directory\Block\Data` with following method `getCountryHtmlSelect()` with following script, but it's not executing.

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Block\Data" type="Magenticians\Modulecontact\Block\Data" /> 
</config>
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Magenticians\Modulecontact\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Data extends \Magento\Directory\Block\Data
{

    public function getCountryHtmlSelect($defValue = null, $name = 'country_id', $id = 'country', $title = 'Country')
    {
        exit;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me where is your di.xml file avilable?

Answer (score 1):

Seems your class has no closing brace. It can cause an error. Additional do not forget to clean cache and remove all files in the `var/generation` or `generated` directory (from Magento root) or just run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

You can check the code using next script in the root of Magento:

Create file `testsomething.php`:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$block = $obj->get('\Magento\Directory\Block\Data');
echo get_class($block);
```

<sup>[How can I bootstrap Magento 2 in a test.php script?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-bootstrap-magento-2-in-a-test-php-script/40848#40848)</sup>

Open this file in the browser (`http://yormagentohost.com/testsomething.php`). Result should looks like this:

> Magenticians\Modulecontact\Block\Data

I tested this code locally and for me it works fine.

Comment: i done all things and i am able to override different block classes expect this

Comment: Maybe some other module overwriten this class too? Check what is returned by a `get_class' function in the template or somewhere else where you can access the block object. I'll update my answer.

Comment: your code is useful, it showing my overrider class but method not applying

Comment: @Ramesh where you checking the overwriten class on the frontend?

Comment: @sergey..yes on fontend

Comment: @Ramesh but where exactly on frontend? I cant find a place where this block is used (cant check it) :(