Magento 2.4.7 Bootstrap Script Error PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Magento\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor
After upgrading from Magento Open Source 2.4.6 to 2.4.7 custom PHP scripts that Bootstrap Magento 2 are failing to run with the error
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Magento\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor\Plugin\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor::aroundLaunch(): Return value must be of type Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface, array returned in /var/www/dev/magento2/vendor/magento/module-application-performance-monitor/Plugin/ApplicationPerformanceMonitor.php:38

Bootstrap script is based on this example https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76382/7863
public function launch()
    {
        $this->run();
        return $this->_response;
    }

If I dump $this->_response I get the correct output from my script, I need to return this as value of type Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface.

The aroundLaunch method in the Magento\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor\Plugin\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor plugin requires the turn type to be Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface. Therefore, the launch method in your custom PHP script must also return a value of type Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface.
Let's debug the issue:

I assume your current launch method in the AbstractApp class (scripts/abstract.php) has the following content. Please note that I replaced the property from _response to response to utilize the constructor promotion property feature in PHP 8.

public function launch()
    {
        $this->run();
        return $this->response;
    }

Replace it with the following content:
public function launch()
{
    $this->run();

    if ($this->response instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface) {
        echo '$this->response is instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface'. "\n";
    } else {
        echo '$this->response is NOT instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface'. "\n";
    }
    var_dump(get_class($this->response));
    var_dump($this->response);
    die;
    return $this->response;
}


Edit the vendor/magento/module-application-performance-monitor/Plugin/ApplicationPerformanceMonitor.php file to add the following line at the beginning of the around Launch method:

echo 'triggered aroundLaunch ApplicationPerformanceMonitor plugin'. "\n";

Then run the script: php scripts/delete-category.php
Then provide with me the out.
Here is my output:
triggered aroundLaunch ApplicationPerformanceMonitor plugin
$this->response is instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
string(47) "Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor"
object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor)#140 (19) {
  ["metadata":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["content":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["version":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["headers":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["recommendedReasonPhrases":protected]=>
  array(64) {
    [100]=>
    string(8) "Continue"
    [101]=>
    string(19) "Switching Protocols"
    [102]=>
    string(10) "Processing"
    [200]=>
    string(2) "OK"
    [201]=>
    string(7) "Created"
    [202]=>
    string(8) "Accepted"
    [203]=>
    string(29) "Non-Authoritative Information"
    [204]=>
    string(10) "No Content"
    [205]=>
    string(13) "Reset Content"
    [206]=>
    string(15) "Partial Content"
    [207]=>
    string(12) "Multi-status"
    [208]=>
    string(16) "Already Reported"
    [226]=>
    string(7) "IM Used"
    [300]=>
    string(16) "Multiple Choices"
    [301]=>
    string(17) "Moved Permanently"
    [302]=>
    string(5) "Found"
    [303]=>
    string(9) "See Other"
    [304]=>
    string(12) "Not Modified"
    [305]=>
    string(9) "Use Proxy"
    [306]=>
    string(12) "Switch Proxy"
    [307]=>
    string(18) "Temporary Redirect"
    [308]=>
    string(18) "Permanent Redirect"
    [400]=>
    string(11) "Bad Request"
    [401]=>
    string(12) "Unauthorized"
    [402]=>
    string(16) "Payment Required"
    [403]=>
    string(9) "Forbidden"
    [404]=>
    string(9) "Not Found"
    [405]=>
    string(18) "Method Not Allowed"
    [406]=>
    string(14) "Not Acceptable"
    [407]=>
    string(29) "Proxy Authentication Required"
    [408]=>
    string(16) "Request Time-out"
    [409]=>
    string(8) "Conflict"
    [410]=>
    string(4) "Gone"
    [411]=>
    string(15) "Length Required"
    [412]=>
    string(19) "Precondition Failed"
    [413]=>
    string(17) "Content Too Large"
    [414]=>
    string(12) "URI Too Long"
    [415]=>
    string(22) "Unsupported Media Type"
    [416]=>
    string(21) "Range Not Satisfiable"
    [417]=>
    string(18) "Expectation Failed"
    [418]=>
    string(12) "I'm a teapot"
    [422]=>
    string(21) "Unprocessable Content"
    [423]=>
    string(6) "Locked"
    [424]=>
    string(17) "Failed Dependency"
    [425]=>
    string(9) "Too Early"
    [426]=>
    string(16) "Upgrade Required"
    [428]=>
    string(21) "Precondition Required"
    [429]=>
    string(17) "Too Many Requests"
    [431]=>
    string(31) "Request Header Fields Too Large"
    [444]=>
    string(34) "Connection Closed Without Response"
    [451]=>
    string(29) "Unavailable For Legal Reasons"
    [499]=>
    string(21) "Client Closed Request"
    [500]=>
    string(21) "Internal Server Error"
    [501]=>
    string(15) "Not Implemented"
    [502]=>
    string(11) "Bad Gateway"
    [503]=>
    string(19) "Service Unavailable"
    [504]=>
    string(15) "Gateway Timeout"
    [505]=>
    string(26) "HTTP Version not supported"
    [506]=>
    string(23) "Variant Also Negotiates"
    [507]=>
    string(20) "Insufficient Storage"
    [508]=>
    string(13) "Loop Detected"
    [510]=>
    string(12) "Not Extended"
    [511]=>
    string(31) "Network Authentication Required"
    [599]=>
    string(29) "Network Connect Timeout Error"
  }
  ["statusCode":protected]=>
  int(200)
  ["reasonPhrase":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["headersSent"]=>
  NULL
  ["contentSent":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["headersSentHandler":"Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response":private]=>
  NULL
  ["isRedirect":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["request":protected]=>
  object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)#130 (5) {
    ["pathInfo"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["requestString"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["module"]=>
    NULL
    ["controller"]=>
    NULL
    ["action"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["cookieManager":protected]=>
  object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager)#128 (4) {
    ["scope":"Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager":private]=>
    object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieScope)#142 (4) {
      ["sensitiveCookieMetadata":"Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieScope":private]=>
      NULL
      ["publicCookieMetadata":"Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieScope":private]=>
      NULL
      ["cookieMetadata":"Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieScope":private]=>
      NULL
      ["cookieMetadataFactory":"Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieScope":private]=>
      object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory)#143 (1) {
        ["objectManager":"Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory":private]=>
        object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager)#53 (0) {
        }
      }
    }
    ["reader":"Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager":private]=>
    object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieReader)#138 (0) {
    }
    ["logger":"Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager":private]=>
    object(Magento\Framework\Logger\LoggerProxy)#21 (2) {
      ["objectManager":"Magento\Framework\Logger\LoggerProxy":private]=>
      object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager)#53 (0) {
      }
      ["logger":"Magento\Framework\Logger\LoggerProxy":private]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["httpHeader":"Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager":private]=>
    object(Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header)#147 (2) {
      ["_request":protected]=>
      object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)#130 (5) {
        ["pathInfo"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["requestString"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["module"]=>
        NULL
        ["controller"]=>
        NULL
        ["action"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["_converter":protected]=>
      object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils)#136 (0) {
      }
    }
  }
  ["cookieMetadataFactory":protected]=>
  object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory)#143 (1) {
    ["objectManager":"Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory":private]=>
    object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager)#53 (0) {
    }
  }
  ["context":protected]=>
  object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context\Interceptor)#146 (6) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["default":protected]=>
    array(2) {
      ["website"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["customer_group"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["serializer":"Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context":private]=>
    object(Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json)#129 (0) {
    }
    ["deploymentConfig":"Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context":private]=>
    NULL
    ["pluginList":"Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context\Interceptor":private]=>
    object(Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList)#156 (0) {
    }
    ["subjectType":"Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context\Interceptor":private]=>
    string(34) "Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context"
  }
  ["dateTime":protected]=>
  object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime)#139 (0) {
  }
  ["sessionConfig":"Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http":private]=>
  object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface\Proxy)#152 (1) {
    ["i"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["pluginList":"Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor":private]=>
  object(Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList)#156 (0) {
  }
  ["subjectType":"Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor":private]=>
  string(35) "Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http"
}


It seems that you modified the launch method. I tested the script shared by Luke Rodgers but it works as expected since the value of $this->response is object Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor, which is an instance of \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface.
I updated my answer to provide additional steps to debug this issue.

Thankyou for this, I will check my code. It is worth noting this is also an update from PHP8.2 to PHP8.3

@paj I tested on PHP 8.2.11, but I don't think this matters.
Could you provide me with the output with my suggestion? If necessary, I can use PHP 8.3 to verify it.

To return the data correctly using the Magento Bootstrap example here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76382/7863
Modify the launch method
public function launch()
{
    $this->_response->setContent($this->run());
    return $this->_response;

} 

Then retrieve your original custom data using
$data=$app->launch()->getContent();


It seems that something is wrong with your project. I tested the script shared by Luke Rodgers and don't need to create the response object manually and it works as expected. The value of $this->response is object Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor, which is an instance of \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface.

Worth noting this is PHP8.3.6

I tested on PHP 8.2.11, but I don't think this matters.

OK I have modified the original script quite a lot and it has ran in all versions of Magento up to 2.4.7. Using $this->_response->setContent($this->run()); seems to work for me now. Thankyou for your help.

I got it. If you still need to deep dive into this issue, I can provide you the clean content scripts based on Luke's post.
